# How does one do a javascript slideshow in a grid container?

Tags: css

I am having issue with my slide show not showing in the  using CSS grid container. I have had it working outside of a grid container. I am trying to learn and it is a pulled the example from W3schools as I normally don't do web development. I was wondering if this was an issue with my CSS or is it something else? Am I nesting it wrong? Is there a certain way slide shows work in CSS grid container? Or what else it could it be?

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: .25fr 1.75fr 1.75fr .25fr;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header"
        "nav main main checkboxes"
        "nav main main checkboxes"
        "footer footer footer footer";
    /*grid-gap: 0.2em */
    ;
}

/* Navagation section */
/* nav section removed */

main {
    /*background: #BF3F7F; */
    grid-area: main;

}

main * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

main .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

main .mySlides {
    display: none;
}

main .prev,
main .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

main .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

main .prev:hover,
main .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

main .text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

main .numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

main .active {
    background-color: #717171;
}

main .fade {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script scr="../template.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="grid">
        <nav>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <!-- System  Assebmly -->
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">Assembly</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <!--Links here-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <!-- Logging In-->
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">Loging In</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="Logging_In/AtUSDAOffice/AtUSDAOffice.html">At USDA Office</a>
                            <a href="Logging_In/Remote/Remote.html">Remote</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <!-- Basic Applications -->
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">Basic Applications Setup</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="Basic_Applications/Outlook/Outlook.html">Outlook</a>
                            <!-- Links here-->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <!-- Agency Appications -->
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">Agency Applications Setup</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <!--Links Here -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <h1>Welcome </h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="slideshow-container">


                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">1 / 23</div>
                    <img src="1_Instructions.jpeg">
                    <div class="text">Instructions</div>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">2 / 23</div>
                    <img src="2_Computer.jpeg">
                    <div class="text">Inventory NRCS Computer</div>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="3_numbertext">3 / 23</div>
                    <img src="DockTopDown.jpeg">
                    <div class="text">Inventory Dock</div>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <div class="numbertext">4 / 23</div>
                    <img src="4_Keyboard.jpeg">
                    <div class="text">Inventory Keyboard</div>
                </div>



            </div>
            <script>
                currentSlide(1);
            </script>

        </main>
        <div id="checkboxes">checkboxes</div>
        <footer>

            Copyright &copy
            <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> reserved.

        </footer>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It may clarify the issue if you remove extraneous HTML elements and focus only on the slideshow elements, e.g. container and container legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is not running because the `src` attribute in your `script` tag is misspelled. (`src` stands for "source")

```
<script scr="../template.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="../template.js"></script>
```

Once you've fixed that, there are a couple other things you might consider fixing:

1. In `template.js`, you're running `showSlides(0)`. However, since the `script` tag that loads `template.js` is in the head of the html, it runs before any content is loaded, so you end up with this error in the browser console:

   ```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
       at showSlides (template.js:27:28)
       at template.js:2:1
   ```

   Instead of adding that loose `<script> currentSlide(1); </script>` tag in the body of your html, which is easy to lose track of, you can add an `onload` handler in `template.js`:

   ```
   let slideIndex = 1;
   window.onload = () => currentSlide(slideIndex);
   ```
2. In your `showSlides` function, you are finding all html elements with the classname `dot`, but you have no such elements in your html. This is resulting in another error, since you're trying to manipulate the classname of an element that doesn't exist. Either remove the code that finds and modifies the dots, or add the dots to your html.